Property of the Hodge-Star operator
I am following the book "Riemannian Geometry and Geometric Analysis" by Jost, and at some point there is written the following property of the Hodge-Star operator without proof. Let $V$ be a real vector space, $\bigwedge^p V$ its p-fold exterior algebra, (with some orientation in order to define $\star$).
Let $A$ be a $d\times d$ matrix, and $f_1,...,f_p\in V$. It follows from the rules of multilinear algebra that:
$$\star(Af_1\wedge A f_2...\wedge A f_p)=det(A)\star (f_1\wedge...\wedge f_p)$$
I've tried proving this for some basis, hoping it would extend linearly, but I am not able to finish a clean proof without hand-waving some indices. For the moment I have only used the linearity of $\star$. I guess i'm missing something. I really could use some help!

Maybe try doing it in dimensions 2 and 3 without using any summation signs or Einstein convention? Dimension 4 might also be useful. I agree it’s confusing.

My answer gives a more explicit way of seeing this is false, but here is a more fundamental way: it does not scale correctly. Make the substitution $A \mapsto \alpha A$ for any scalar $\alpha$. The the LHS scales by $\alpha^p$ but the RHS scales by $\alpha^{\dim V}$. Now divide by $\alpha^p$; the LHS is independent of $\alpha$, but the RHS is not unless $p=\dim V$, which is absurd. Thus your identity can only hold when $p=\dim V$ (which it does, but it's merely a direct application of the exterior algebra characterization of determinant).

$
\newcommand\lcontr{\mathbin\rfloor}
$The identity stated is false. Consider the 3D case, let $p=2$, and let $A$ be the reflection through the plane defined by $f_1,f_2$ (which we assume to be linearly independent). Then $A(f_1)\wedge A(f_2) = f_1\wedge f_2$ and $\det(A) = -1$ so
$$
  \star(A(f_1)\wedge A(f_2)) = \star(f_1\wedge f_2)
$$
but
$$
  (\det A)\,{\star(f_1\wedge f_2)} = -{\star(f_1\wedge f_2)}.
$$
The correct statement is as follows.
If $V$ is $n$-dimensional, then it can be taken as a definition of the determinant that
$$
  A(I) = (\det f)I
$$
for all $I \in {\bigwedge^n}V$, where we define
$$
  A(f_1\wedge\dotsb\wedge f_p) = A(f_1)\wedge\dotsb\wedge A(f_p)
$$
on ${\bigwedge^p}V$ for any $p$. The inner product on $V$ extends naturally to ${\bigwedge^p}V$, and can be explicitly computed as
$$
  (f_1\wedge\dotsb\wedge f_p)\cdot(g_1\wedge\dotsb\wedge g_p) = \det\Bigl(f_i\cdot g_j\Bigr)_{i,j=1}^p.
$$
This gives an inner product on the whole exterior algebra, where $X\cdot Y = 0$ if $X,Y$ have different grade.
The (left) contraction $\lcontr : {\bigwedge}V\times{\bigwedge V} \mapsto {\bigwedge V}$ is the adjoint of the exterior product: for all multivectors $X,Y,Z$
$$
  (X\lcontr Y)\cdot Z = X\cdot(Y\wedge Z).
$$
From this, you can prove that
$$
  A(\bar A(X)\lcontr Y) = X\lcontr A(Y)
$$
where $\bar A$ is the adjoint of $A$ under the inner product. You can also prove that
$$
  \star X = X\lcontr I
$$
where $I \in {\bigwedge^n}V$ is the volume element associated with $\star$.
Finally, using the fact that $\det(A) = \det(\bar A)$ we get for any multivector $X$
$$
  \det(A)\,{\star X} = X\lcontr A(I) = A(\bar A(X)\lcontr I) = A(\star\bar A(X)).
$$
